# Where can I find the procedure called from this Excel VBA Application.Run statement?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with an Excel VBA "Sub" that contains a statement like:

```
Application.Run ("Menu_SomeProcedure")
```

which is calling some code or functionality which I need to inspect but I'm unable to find the implementation of "Menu_SomeProcedure" anywhere in the VBA module code.  Where should I look to find it?  I am using Microsoft Office Excel 2003.

Comment: What happens when you step through the code? "Application.Run : Runs a macro or calls a function. This can be used to run a macro written in Visual Basic or the Microsoft Excel macro language, or to run a function in a DLL or XLL."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be coming from an add-in.

Look for any referenced add-ins to your app:  Tools/Add-Ins from the file menu.

I think you can do this in the VBA IDE as well.  There is an "Add-Ins" option available in 2007...I would think one exists in 2003.

Lastly, you could click "Tools/References" in the IDE to check for any peculiar DLLs references.